# SQL Developer 3.0 , can't run the command

Tags: oracle

I am using Toad 9.7, when I run command "describe my_storedprocedure", it can get results. Then in SQL Developer 3.0, I use same user name / password to login same Oracle database, use same command, it can't show the content of that storedproc .

Do you know why ?

Comment: you can press CTRL and click on the name of the procedure.

Comment: It does work in SQL Developer 3.0.04 for me, so it should for you.

Answer (score 0):

To see the content of a stored procedure:

1. doubleclick on the procedure name so that it is highlighted
2. right click to get the context menu
3. select "Popup describe"